# Token accounts and "setAuthority"

Tags: spl-token, associated-token-account, token-account

I've been trying to understand the intended use cases of `setAuthority` function in the context of Token accounts. For Mint accounts, it is clear that `setAuthority` can be used to set the mint and freeze authorities. However, I am quite puzzled how this function is to be used with Token accounts.

According to the [documentation](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#setAuthority) the `setAuthority` function supports two `AuthorityType`s that are intended to be used with Token accounts: `AccountOwner` and `CloseAccount`. I have been trying to use it on my localnet, but with no success -- in all my trials the transactions fail with the following error: `Transaction failed to sanitize accounts offsets correctly`.

That being said, my concrete questions are:

1. Can `setAuthority` be used to change the "owner" of an auxiliary (i.e. non-associated) Token account? By "owner" I of course mean the pubkey specified in the Token account data since Token accounts must *always* be owned by the Token program.
2. Can `setAuthority` be used to change the "close authority" of a Token account (auxiliary or proper ATA)? If so, can the "owner" also close the account, or does that privilege then only belong to the "close authority"? Normally, the Token accounts are initialized with undefined "close authority", but they can be closed by the "owner".
3. Why does the `setAuthority` transaction fail with the above error? I've tried it on auxiliary token accounts and associated token accounts that were freshly generated (empty) as well as used ones...

I would be also happy if someone could fill me in on these details (the official SPL documentation is very meager...). Thanks!

Comment: I think the setAuthority just allows you to delegate your tokens to another account

Comment: Delegation seems to be an independent functionality -- if you look at the definition of Token stuct there are separate "delegate" and "delegate_amount" fields in addition to the "owner" and "close_authority".